# Nuxt can't resolve css imports

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to set a global css for my nuxt project, I added the css file path in nuxt.config.js, when I executed:

```
npm run dev
```

I ran into this error:

```
 ERROR  in ./assets/main.css                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            friendly-errors 10:22:02

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 10:22:02
Error: Can't resolve 'style.css' in 'C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\assets'
    at onError (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:166:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:249:35)
    at C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Users\foo\Desktop\bar\nuxt_test\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
```

This is just sample code to reproduce the problem - I reproduce it by adding these files after generating a fresh nuxt app using:

```
npx create-nuxt-app nuxt_test
```

main.css:

```
@import url("style.css");
```

style.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(../assets/roboto.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
import pkg from './package'

export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  css: ['~assets/main.css'],

  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the tilde (`~`) in `css: ['~assets/main.css'],` I think you mistyped it here (Did you mean `~/assets/main.css`)?

Comment: But I don't know, why you use tilde `~` at all. This is dependent on the user, who is running the script

Comment: @yunzen I did by following the example provided in nuxt:

Comment: which one? Do you have a link for that?

Comment: @yunzen about `~` check the warning in the docs [link] (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/) the example [link] (https://nuxtjs.org/examples/global-css/)

Comment: If I import style.css directly it will work fine but when importing a css importing another css, will cause an error

Comment: The error is definitely the import of `style.css` into `main.css`. I guess style.css is in the assets folder so in theory what you have should work, but it doesn't. Maybe try `@import "style.css"` or even `@import "./style.css"`

Comment: @andrew1325 I have tried what you proposed by It didn't work, you can see in the error the message the directory of ` style.css ` is correct, but can't be resolved !

Comment: @yunzen a `~` in nuxt's context is an alias to refer to nuxt's current working directory. You can read about it [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure#aliases).

Comment: @Aaimsh instead of using `@import..` in .css file itself, why not add `style.css` to `nuxt.config.js` like you added `main.css`?

Comment: @Mjh That will work, but some projects have many css files so we wrap them in one main.css by importing them

Comment: @Aaimsh well, you're on an actual framework (nuxt), why not simply use it as it was intended? It's a bad habit to mix how things work (in your case - how css is imported), you'll just end up misusing nuxt entirely down the line. If I were you, I'd fix this problem once and for all and I'd handle css imports via nuxt's config. Good luck!

Comment: @Mjh I will give you that, but even if I import a css file in a component It will result the same error

Comment: Try with absolute paths then, `@import "/assets/style.css"`.

Comment: @Mjh I've tried it, its not working, in simple vue app - without nuxt - this will work.

Comment: @Mjh I managed to import the css file in the component using `require('~/assets/style.css')` in the script section, Note: If the css include other css imports will cause the same problem.